# BMW - what happens to car bluetooth phone if I connect audio from iphone via A2DP adaptor?

Tags: bmw, audio, bluetooth

BMW 328i Cab - if I get an A2DP adapter to connect audio from iPhone to the car aux, will I still be able to view contacts, receive and make calls on the car's bluetooth hands free system?

Comment: Does your handsfree system support A2DP?

Comment: I'm not sure. i saw many people suggesting to replace the aux cable with A2DP receiver, but I decided to ask before buying the receiver if this would prevent me from using my car hands free

Comment: A2DP is mostly a streaming audio profile. In theory for a car accessory even the Hands-Free Profile should be supported but I guess it would depend on the manufacturer. Specs should tell you or maybe asking the seller directly/browsing reviews of the item, and also to the ones that suggest its use. You might also want to investigate if theres a way to route the different profile streams to different devices (your existing and the new BT devices) on the phone side

Comment: The easiest way to do it is grab a bluetooth audio receiver which does *not* do calling. When I'm driving I have my bluetooth connected to my car for calling and Siri, an audio receiver plugged into the aux in, and a remote so I can leave the phone in my pocket. It works well.